# Change DisplayName attribute for a property

Tags: .net, winforms, properties, attributes, propertygrid

I am looking for a way to change the value of the `DisplayName` attribute of a property at run-time. Is this even possible in Windows Forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own [TypeDescriptionProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.aspx) for your class, and assign it at runtime to single object (or entire class) using [TypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.aspx). Also look into [GetTypeDescriptor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typedescriptionprovider.gettypedescriptor.aspx) and [GetProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icustomtypedescriptor.getproperties.aspx), and finally [AttributeArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.memberdescriptor.attributearray.aspx).

In general creating your own type descriptor is not so hard, but you need to read msdn carefully and do a lot of tries.